# Shortcut to User Home Folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts, home-directory

I want to create a short cut to the *System Folder* version of my home folder.  Actually, I want to do this for every user, but lets focus on a single user.  I do not want to create a link to `C:\users\%USERNAME`, while it is the same location, the view settings can be different and this for some reason confuses users.  It sure seems likely that there must be a way to create a shortcut to this in the same way it is possible to create the [master control panel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Master_Control_Panel_shortcut) shortcut, but I haven't been able to find the correct GUID while searching.

When I am talking about the **System Folder** version, the highlighted folder is what I want.

[image: Desktop - Home Folder]
[image: Home Folder - System]

I **do not want** to create a shortcut to this view of the folder `C:\users\%USERNAME%`.

[image: Home Folder - c:\users\username]

Comment: [Is there a list of Windows special directories/shortcuts (like %TEMP%)?](//superuser.com/q/217504) shows %userprofile% and more.

Comment: Consider accepting [Raystafarian's answer](https://superuser.com/a/398937/358766). It's a much more easily memorable method than the current accepted answer.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro but that didn't really answer the question I was asking.  Going to `%userprofile%` doesn't have the same result result as `::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The GUID for the Shell Extention (i.e. special) version of the User's home Folder is `{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}`.

A link based on that GUID will open the Home folder of the signed-in user.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  In case anyone else cares you can start a new explorer Window using a command like `explorer.exe ::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}`.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution has stopped working with the Creator's Update to Windows 10.  The solution is to navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow\command` and delete the new key `DelegateExecute`.

Comment: @HonoredMule cannot reproduce.  The `explorer.exe ::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}` shortcut seems to be working perfectly fine on my 1703 Windows 10 system.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the variation I use, supplying %USERPROFILE% (I want the real path so I can navigate by keyboard to parents).  In that case, the content of DelegateExecute seems to override the path.  Also, putting the path in DelegateExecute instead (Default) breaks launching explorer with an infinite launch loop.

Comment: Somehow I find Unix' `~` easier to memorize than Windows' `::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}`, but both do the equivalent things.

Answer (score 42):

Link to `%userprofile%` will work

Answer (score 0):

This manual registry edit worked for me on SRV 2016 and will prob work for older OSs.

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu

& 
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel

Make a DWord with the ID {59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee} and set it to 0.

This sets the default, individual users can overwrite.

Answer (score -1):

Improving on to what Mattias Åslund said, you could go to the users file ( "C:\Users" ) by doing something similar to:

> cd %userprofile%
>
> cd..

Unfortunately, from what i know, you cant do something like:

> cd..%userprofile%

Comment: This is about navigating within GUI, not a shell.  I want the GUI to go to the home folder, and not the expand the full path.  Yes I know that they are both the same location, but they operate differently in explorer.  The breadcrumbs are different, and the apparent sub folders are different.